# Prove that $\operatorname{det} A\leq \|A\|^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Assume that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix  and $\|A\|$ is the operator norm of $A$.  Prove that $\operatorname{det}A\leq \|A\|^n$.

Comment: Note that: If A^T=A and all eigenvalue of A is real, then the state is true since peano theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sigma_1 \leq .... \leq \sigma_n$ be the singular values of $A$. Then

$$|\det(A)|^2=\det(A^*A)=\sigma_1 ... \sigma_n \leq (\sigma_n)^n=\| A \|^{2n}$$

Comment: If A is a matrix of rotation of 90 degrees, then || A|| is not equal maximal its eigenvalue.

Comment: tks for your answer, I think if A is a symmetric and eigenvalue of A is real, then your answer is true.

Comment: tks, i understand

Comment: @user462020 $\sigma$ are not the eigenvalues of $A$. They are the singular values, meaning the eigenvalues of $A^*A$.

Comment: @user462020 Note that $$\|Ax\|_2^2=(Ax)^*(Ax)=x^T A^*Ax \leq x^T \sigma_n x $$ with equality if and only if $x$ is an eigenvector for $A^*A$ with eigenvalue $\sigma_n$.

Comment: thks for your reply, i clear

Comment: @user462020 Basically, it is the idea you tried to used, but applyed to $B=A^*A$ instead of $A$. If your matrix is real, then $A^*=A^T$.